# How to extract weight and other meta data from a text block?

Tags: php, regex, text

Example texts that needs to process are :

> GLENSTAL EXTRA MATURE COL CHEDDAR 200 GMS, ORIGINAL WAFFLES CO.
>   ENGLISH 130G, LIFCO-SHREDDED MOZAREAL-500GM, CAPRICON TASTY BREAD
>   -BIG, LUSINE MULTI GRAIN SLICED BREAD, ORGANIC MIXED FRUITS JUICE 10X200ML, COLA 330ML(016) PHOENIX ORGANIC, FRUITS JUICE 10X 200ML,
>   ORGANIC FRUITS JUICE 500ML10X

From this text I have to extract the weight, unit and if pack are available as like "10X or 6X". I tried to solve it using regex but its not working on all conditions.

The code I tried with is:

```
$weight_unit = explode(" ", $title_string);
 $units = array("LITRE", "LTRS", "LTR", "LIT", "GMS", "LBS", "KG", "GM", "GR", "ML", "OZ", "LB", "G", "L");
 for ($m = 0; $m < sizeof($weight_unit); $m++) {
   foreach ($units as $unit) {
     if (preg_match('/^[0-9A-Z.]*([0-9][A-Z]|[A-Z][0-9])[0-9A-Z]*$/',
          $weight_unit[$m]) && strpos($weight_unit[$m], $unit) !== FALSE) {
          $product["weight"] = preg_replace("/[A-Za-z]/", '', $weight_unit[$m]);
          $product["unit"] = $unit;
          break;
      }
   }
 }
```

Comment: Your question would be much more valuable to future readers and to volunteers that wish to post an answer if you also post your desired output given your sample input.  What do you want to do with `-BIG`?  How exactly do you want `COLA 330ML(016) PHOENIX ORGANIC` to be parsed?  Please post your complete desired output array because I would like to offer a comprehensive and optimized answer so that you can award the green tick and this question can be deemed sufficiently resolved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may not be worth your trouble to try to do all this with just one regex. Maybe you can get it working, but the next person to work on it will be have a hard time, unless she is used to whistling into a modem. :-)  Let's try a series of nested loops.

```
$txt = "GLENSTAL EXTRA MATURE COL CHEDDAR 200 GMS, ORIGINAL WAFFLES CO. ENGLISH 130G, LIFCO-SHREDDED MOZAREAL-500GM, CAPRICON TASTY BREAD -BIG, LUSINE MULTI GRAIN SLICED BREAD, ORGANIC MIXED FRUITS JUICE 10X200ML, COLA 330ML(016) PHOENIX ORGANIC, FRUITS JUICE 10X 200ML, ORGANIC FRUITS JUICE 500ML10X";   
$units = array("LITRE", "LTRS", "LTR", "LIT", "GMS", "LBS", "KG", "GM", "GR", "ML", "OZ", "LB", "G", "L");
/* break up your string at the commas, so you handle each item by itself */
$items = preg_split("/\s*,\s*/", $txt);

/* work through the items one by one */
foreach ($items as $item) {
    $amtnum = 1;
    $amtunit = "";
    $packnum = "1";

    /* break up the item description into tokens, where 
     * each number string and letter string gets its own token.
     * deal with (123) parenthesized number strings as well.
     *   e.g.   "FRUITS JUICE" "10" "X" "200" "ML"
     *   and    "COLA" "330" "ML" "(016)" "PHOENIX ORGANIC"
     */
    $toks = preg_split("/(\(\d+\)|\d+|[^\d\(\)]+)/", $item,-1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE|PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
    /* work backward through array of tokens, using array_pop */
    while ($tok = array_pop($toks)) {
        /* is the present token in your array of units? */
        if (in_array(strtoupper($tok), $units)) {
            /* yes. grab next token as the number of units */
            $amtunit = $tok;
            $amtnum = array_pop($toks);
        }
        /* is this an X (for a 16X pack or some such thing ? */
        if ($tok == 'X') {
            /* yes, grab next token as the number of items in the pack */
            $packnum = array_pop($toks);
        }
        /* do what you will with the result */
        echo $amtnum, $amtunit, $packnum;
    }
}
```

This line is the key to this solution to your problem. Let us examine it.

```
    $toks = preg_split(
            "/(\(\d+\)|\d+|[^\d\(\)]+)/", 
            $item,-1, 
            PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE|PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

`preg_split` splits up a string into an array. `PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE` as a modifier means to include in the result array the stuff from the regular expression.   `PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY` means don't include empty strings in the result array.

Let's look at the regular expression itself. I'll add spaces to make it easier to read.

```
(  \(\d+\)  |  \d+  |  [^\d\(\)]+  )
```

It starts and ends with parentheses `()`. This goes with `PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE`.

It then contains three alternative matching expressions, separated by `|`.

The first is a parenthesis, a number, and a parenthesis.  That matches the string `(016)` in your test data set.

The second is a plain number.  That matches stuff like "300".

The third is a string of letters, spaces, etc, anything except numbers and parentheses. That matches "GMS" and "FRUITS JUICE" for example.

This is probably a reasonably robust way to use regular expressions to do this parsing job.

Answer (score 3):

You can try with:

```
(\d+X\s?)?\d+\s?(LITRE|LTRS|LTR|LIT|GMS|LBS|KG|GM|GR|ML|OZ|LB|G|L)(\d+X\s?)?
```

if you want only these units to match. In regex:

- `(\d+X\s?)?` - may match one or more digits with X (10X, etc.),
- `\d+\s?` - one or more digits and one or none whitespace character
- `(LITRE|LTRS|LTR|LIT|GMS|LBS|KG|GM|GR|ML|OZ|LB|G|L)` - alternatives of
  your units,
- `(\d+X\s?)?` - may match one or more digits with X after units

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/xX4qI9/1)